# How to remove most water from food when cooling them down before putting to a refrigerator?

Tags: food-preservation, refrigerator

Today I baked some liquid eggs, see the picture below. After baking, there was no liquid in the eggs any more. I waited till them became lukewarm, and put them inside a plastic bag used for packaging frozen vegetables before. I continue to keep the bag of baked eggs at the room temperature, and after a while, I found a lot of water dripping from the outside of the bag.

I doubt that the bag is leaking. But why is there so much water?
The liquid eggs are no longer liquid, why give off so much water when cooling down?

Shall I avoid the water before putting the baked eggs into the freezer?

How can I deal the water from cooked food better than letting the water dripping from the bag?

I remember after I baked a turkey and put its pieces in plastic bags into the freezer, I found some ice in the same bags. Did the ice also come into being for the same reason as the water from the baked eggs?

[image]

Comment: I think your answer will need to be about eggs specifically. Most foods don't give off water like this.

Comment: Water vapour in the air trapped in the bag when cooling down even from lukewarm bag will cause condensation.

Comment: Water dripping from outside the bag? That makes no sense to me. There is no purpose to keep the eggs at room temperature for a while if you plan to freeze (or refrigerate) them.

Comment: I, like Paparazzi, am really confused here.  You say the water appeared only *outside* of the bag (and not *in* the bag)?  The reason for the turkey ice is partially related to Namphibian's comment about condensation from the air and likely partly due to sublimation and re-freezing of moisture from the food surface in the freezer (aka the stuff that causes "freezer burn" over longer periods).  But the water on the *outside* of the egg bag is very strange.

Comment: There was some water  inside the bag, but there was more outside the bag. @Athanasius

Comment: Condensation should not form on a bag (or object) at  temperature greater than room temperature.  Condensation only forms at the dew point temperature.  The dew point is always air temperature or less.   Unless the bag is leaking what you are reporting does not make physical sense.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is pure and simple. Condensation. Anytime you put anything into plastic that is not cold it will cause it to sweat. The best way to freeze anything is to place it in your freezer, uncovered and unwrapped immediately or within 5 to 10 minutes after removing it from the oven. Once it is frozen, and that should take anywhere from1 to 2 hours depending on what you are freezing, remove it from freezer and wrap quickly and immediately, making sure it remains well frozen, then return to freezer.This is called flash freezing and is the best way to keep the integrity of your food intact.  When defrosting your food, especially if it is something like a piece of frosted cake, unwrap the item as soon as you remove it from your freezer, then let it defrost. Hope this helps!